# htaccess redirect to query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use an e-commerce service called Ecwid. I've set up my site so that i can avoid ecwids default storefront. But i still need to access the shopping cart. I want to prevent customers from access the default storfront and be redirected to the shopping cart.

From:  https://example.com/store.html

To:  https://example.com/store.html?store-page=cart

Comment: search to do it by configuration of htaccess

Comment: You probably want to ask the support team of that service. They should be able to help you.